# Issue with tagDatabase operation in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I need to add support of liquibase to existing application with existing database. I set up maven plugin and when I'm running it it creates Liquibase tables. As a next step I want to tag database at the very beginning to create a tag for rollback.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-plugin:1.9.3.0:tag (tag.database) on project liquitest: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.
exception.JDBCException: Cannot tag an empty database -> [Help 1]
```

Is it possible to tag initial state of database when liquibase was just added and no changesets were applied?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is not possible, because tag is stored in DATABASECHANGELOG table, and if there are no records there, it is not possible to store it.
The workaround is to add a dummy migration, for examle:

```
<changeset id="1" author="qqq">
<sql>select 1 from dual</sql>
</changeset>
```